# Mapping to one CoreData attribute from a collection of elements using RestKit RKDynamicMapping

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to map to one CoreData attribute from the following JSON:

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "stock": {
            "inStock": true,
            "inStockBeforeMaxAdvanceOrderingDate": false
        },
        "url": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "manufacturer": "Demo",
        "images": [
            {
                "format": "thumbnail",
                "imageType": "PRIMARY",
                "url": "/imageURL/xx.jpg"
            },
            {
                "format": "thumbnailGrid",
                "imageType": "PRIMARY",
                "url": "/imageURL/xxx.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "productFees": [
            [
                "EMPTY",
                "0.0"
            ]
        ],
        "name": "demo product"
    }
]
```

}

I am trying to extract only the thumbnailGrid image url from the images collection. In my responses I have a lot of times a collection returned but I am interested only in one field. 
I can setup relationships in CoreData and I have no problems, but because I know that I will match only one resource I would prefer to store in one attribute rather then a relationship.

My product CoreData entity has a thumbnailImageURL attribute.

My Product entity mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectStore:_managedObjectStore];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"stock.inStock":@"inStock",
 @"stock.inStockBeforeMaxAdvanceOrderingDate":@"inStockBeforeMaxAdvanceOrderingDate",
 @"url":@"url",
 @"manufacturer": @"manufacturer",
 @"manufacturerName":@"manufacturerName",
 @"name":@"name",
 }];

RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];

[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"images" toKeyPath:@"thumbnailImageURL" withMapping:dynamicMapping]];

[dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {
    if ([[representation objectForKey:@"format"] isEqualToString:@"thumbnailGrid"]) {
        return ???;
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

I am not sure what to return from Dynamic mapper when the match occurs. Shall I create another RKEntityMapping instance that is a map for the same "Product" entity and map the url to thumbnailImageURL?

Also is it passible to add somehow Dynamic mapper as an attribute rather then a relationship?

Thanks,

Csaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd store it as a collection and then filter it out later. Or, add a method to your managed object subclass which is called to set the collection and then do the filtering there (setting the filter result to your actual attribute). Trying to get RestKit to do this kind of filter is hard (I'm not sure you can do it).